# Modular UI elements and corresponding data

Tags: python, blender

I'm thinking about creating modular UI elements with corresponding data sets. How could this be achieved?

Example:

[ADD ELEMENT TYPE] button - adds UI element of type. Each type should be able to contain different UI elements (properties). Should support a theoretically infinite amount of added elements.

User Interface after adding:

- [ADD ELEMENT TYPE] button
- [ELEMENT TYPE 1]
- [ELEMENT TYPE 2]
- [ELEMENT TYPE 1]
- [ELEMENT TYPE 3]
- ...

[ELEMENT TYPE 1] would e.g. contain one number property and two checkboxes / boolean properties
[ELEMENT TYPE 2] would e.g. contain three number properties etc.

Multiple sets of [ELEMENT TYPE 1] should be able to hold different sets of data!

Don't need working code, just any direction or guideline, please! Is that even possible with Blender and it's Python API?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to make a loop, then append to a set of lists as you go and when you have everything the range() method stops the loop. Then simply call the function

```
import sys

dataset = []

def element1(argv):
    argv = raw_input("add a number or letter")
    for answer in range(1,999999):
        if len(argv) >= 5:  #BOOLEAN
            dataset.append(argv)
            return dataset

print dataset
```

Comment: btw dont use this code i hardly indented and kind of just threw my ideas into nonfunctional code.